# how to check if object reached at level 2 of knockoutjs?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knockoutjs to bind data, I have a json like this:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "ID": "EBED739E30005025B9A4E2E88771B9E2D786B71C",
  "content": "this is comment 1",
  "userName": "Jonh",
  "replies": [
    {
      "ID": "5FE7FF30630519A47B561A2CB1965C5F7395C14B",
      "userName": "Peter",
      "content": "this is reply 2 of comment 1",
      "replies": [
      {
        "ID": "5FE7FF30630519A47B561A2CB1965C5F7395C14B",
        "userName": "Kevin",
         "content": "this is reply 3 of 2"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"success": 1
}
```

And I want how to check if object replies reached at level 2 so I can disable button reply.
And here is html:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-reply">
<div class="ui two column grid" >
    <div class="twelve wide column">
        <span class="neeah-bold" data-bind="text:Username"></span>
        <p data-bind="text: content"></p>
        <span>
            //here I want to disable button if it is a reply leve 2
            <!-- ko if:  typeof replies.replies === "undefined" -->
            <a class="neeah-gray-midium active-reply" data-bind="click: $root.openReply">
                <i class="fa fa-reply fa-1x"></i>
            </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ko if:  typeof replies != 'undefined' -->
    <div class="reply">
        <div class="ui segment show-reply-level"  data-bind="template: { name: 'template-reply', foreach: replies }"></div>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

So how can I check if object replies is level 2 and then I can disable button?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should be able to do something like this:

```
<!-- ko if: $parents.length == 2 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the enable binding:

```
enable: replies.replies().length == 0
```

Then, your `<span>` will become:

```
<span>
     <a class="neeah-gray-midium active-reply" data-bind="click: $root.openReply, enable: replies.replies().length == 0">
            <i class="fa fa-reply fa-1x"></i>
     </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change you logic a bit. I check parents and if element has parent of level2 which has `replies` property then we are on the reply level 2.

```js
var data = {
    "data": [{
         "ID": "EBED739E30005025B9A4E2E88771B9E2D786B71C",
         "content": "this is comment 1",
         "userName": "Jonh",
         "replies": [{
             "ID": "5FE7FF30630519A47B561A2CB1965C5F7395C14B",
             "userName": "Peter",
             "content": "this is reply 2 of comment 1",
             "replies": [{
                "ID": "5FE7FF30630519A47B561A2CB1965C5F7395C14B",
                "userName": "Kevin",
                "content": "this is reply 3 of 2"
             }]
         }],
    }, {
         "ID": "EBED739E30005025B9A4E2E88771B9E2D786B71C",
         "content": "this is comment 1",
         "userName": "Jonh",
         "replies": [{
             "ID": "5FE7FF30630519A47B561A2CB1965C5F7395C14B",
             "userName": "Peter",
             "content": "this is reply 2 of comment 1"
         }],
    }],
    "success": 1,
    openReply: function () {
      alert('Reply');
    }
};
  
ko.applyBindings(data);
```

```css
.neeah-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.reply {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="template-reply">
<div class="ui two column grid">
    <div class="twelve wide column">
        <span class="neeah-bold" data-bind="text:userName"></span>
        <p data-bind="text: content"></p>
        <span>
            <!-- here I want to disable button if it is a reply leve 2 -->
            <!-- ko if: $parents.length < 2 || !$parents[1].replies -->
            <a class="neeah-gray-midium active-reply" data-bind="click: $root.openReply">
                <i class="fa fa-reply fa-1x">Reply</i>
            </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ko if: $data.replies !== undefined -->
    <div class="reply">
        <div class="ui segment show-reply-level" data-bind="template: { name: 'template-reply', foreach: replies }"></div>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'template-reply', foreach: data }"></div>
```

Another slightly more complex option is to pass custom options to template

```js
var data = {
    "data": [{
         "ID": "EBED739E30005025B9A4E2E88771B9E2D786B71C",
         "content": "this is comment 1",
         "userName": "Jonh",
         "replies": [{
             "ID": "5FE7FF30630519A47B561A2CB1965C5F7395C14B",
             "userName": "Peter",
             "content": "this is reply 2 of comment 1",
             "replies": [{
                "ID": "5FE7FF30630519A47B561A2CB1965C5F7395C14B",
                "userName": "Kevin",
                "content": "this is reply 3 of 2"
             }]
         }],
    }, {
         "ID": "EBED739E30005025B9A4E2E88771B9E2D786B71C",
         "content": "this is comment 1",
         "userName": "Jonh",
         "replies": [{
             "ID": "5FE7FF30630519A47B561A2CB1965C5F7395C14B",
             "userName": "Peter",
             "content": "this is reply 2 of comment 1"
         }],
    }],
    "success": 1,
    openReply: function () {
      alert('Reply');
    }
};
  
ko.applyBindings(data);
```

```css
.neeah-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.reply {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="template-reply">
<div class="ui two column grid">
    <div class="twelve wide column">
        <span class="neeah-bold" data-bind="text:userName"></span>
        <p data-bind="text: content"></p>
        <span>
            <!-- here I want to disable button if it is a reply leve 2 -->
            <!-- ko if: level < 2 -->
            <a class="neeah-gray-midium active-reply" data-bind="click: $root.openReply">
                <i class="fa fa-reply fa-1x">Reply</i>
            </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ko if: $data.replies !== undefined -->
    <div class="reply">
        <div class="ui segment show-reply-level" data-bind="template: { name: 'template-reply', foreach: replies.map(function (item) { item.level = $data.level + 1; return item;}) }"></div>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'template-reply', foreach: data.map(function (item) { item.level = 0; return item;}) }"></div>
```